# Load .csv files into dictionary and print keys and values separately

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am having troubles figuring out how to store multiple .csv files into a dictionary and then print the keys and values separately. I have to take 6 .csv files all containing different information and load them into a dictionary(s) and then write a code so that I am able to isolate the key from the various values its associated with so that I can print ie. "animal" eats "prey1, prey2, etc".

I think I have to do each file separately, so 6 different loops to get the right output for each list of key/values, but everything I've tried has given me an error message.
Here is an examples of a csv file and the expected output:

file1.csv:

```
Rabbit,Grass  
Snake,Mouse  
Mouse,Grass
```

Output:

```
Predator and prey:   
"Rabbit eats grass"    
"Snake eats mouse"  
"Mouse eats grass"
```

this is the code I have so far for one file:

```
import sys
import csv

inf = open("file1.csv", "r")
reader = csv.reader(inf)

data = {}
for row in reader:
    for i in data.keys():
        print(data[i], "eats", i)
```

I know its not right but I'm not sure how to isolate a key in a dictionary when its a .csv file. I am new to coding so any help would be greatly appreciated! :)
I am using **python3**.
thanks!!

Comment: A quick (and a bit slow) way is to just use [`csv.DictReader`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader) to load your CSVs as dictionaries, then you can merge them to produce a cumulative results.

Comment: Thanks! Im a little unsure about the format for this in python3 though, as it isn't working for what I'm seeing online.

Comment: Show us some sample data from 2 csv files and expected output

Comment: I have included an example of a file, the rest of the files are the same but with different predators and prey, some include more than one prey.

Answer (score 1):

Well, there are no keys (header fields) or anything in your CSV, just simple value pairs and you just want to print separately the elements of each row which is quite simple:

```
import csv

with open("file1.csv", "r") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
        print(row[0], "eats", row[1])
```

Which should produce:

```
Rabbit eats Grass
Snake eats Mouse
Mouse eats Grass
```

**UPDATE**: If you want to store the data into a dictionary, just use the first value as a key and the second value as one of the values, e.g.:

```
import collections
import csv

# we'll use defaultdict to save us some trouble initializing for each predator
predators = collections.defaultdict(set)  # our final dict, use set to filter out duplicates

files = ["file1.csv", "file2.csv", "file3.csv"]  # all of your CSV files

for file in files:  # go through each CSV file...
    with open(file, "r") as f:  # open it...
        reader = csv.reader(f)  # make a CSV reader
        for row in reader:  # go through it line by line
            predators[row[0]].add(row[1])  # add it to the predators dict

for predator in predators:
    print(predator, "eats", predators[predator])
```

Comment: Thank you! However I am suppose to do it so that all of the data from the file is loaded into a dictionary that describes the prey relationship. The keys in the dictionary will by the names of the predators and the values in the dictionary will be lists of food.

Comment: @DallaxT - well then just construct a dictionary instead of printing the elements, check the update.

Comment: Ohhh okay, thank you!! So rather than initializing each file dict I can use a default?

Comment: @DallaxT - you can use the same `predators` dictionary to 'load' all of your CSVs in, if you need a cumulative list of all of their prey over all of the CSVs. I've updated the example to reflect that.

Answer (score 0):

You should checkout [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/). 
Very good for this sort of thing.

```
df = pd.read_csv('file1.csv', names=['Predator','Prey'])
df['statement'] = df.Predator + ' eats ' + df.Prey

for s in df.statement:
    print(s)
```

If you want a dict of {'predator':'prey'} you could do

```
dic = {pred:prey for pred,prey in df[['Predator','Prey']].values}
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm not sure this format is allowed in python3 though, I get an error message with the =names[ ].